# how to upload image in mysql using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

I am trying to send data in mysql but it returns an error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')

My code is:

```
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const getConnection = require('./database');

// Set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './uploads/',
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
}).single('photo');

router.post('/upload', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const connection = await getConnection();
    await upload(req, res, async(err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error uploading file:', err);
        return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      }

      if (!req.file) {
        console.error('No file uploaded.');
        return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
      }

      const imagePath = req.file.path;
      const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);

      const query = 'INSERT INTO image (photo) VALUES (?)';
      await connection.query(query, [imageBuffer]);
      connection.release();

      res.send('File uploaded and saved to MySQL!');
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

module.exports = router
```

Check my code and please help me solve

Comment: `connection` is `undefined`. `await getConnection();` returns `undefined`.